Android USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED persistent permission for Service
I have an Android service application with a USB host connection to a CDC device.
How can I set permament USB permission without auto start Activity?
I found lot of examples with intent-filter android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED, meta-data.
When I used it, it works. But everytime I reconnect to the USB device, the application is restarted.
I tried to create "startup" activity for service, with android:launchMode="singleInstance", and it works fine. But I don't want any activity.
So is it possible to set "permanent USB permission" without use of activity?
Or second question? Is it possible suspend USB device from application?
